# Find all matching values in a JSON object whose corresponding keys are regex and match a provided string

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a json string of the following type

```json
{
  "[A-Z]+": {
    "k": "test1", 
    "c": "stg1"
  }, 
  "[a-z]+": {
    "k": "test2", 
    "c": "stg2"
  }
}
```

The objective is that given a string, if this string matches the regex pattern of one of the keys, then return the value stored in the `k` field of the first matching object. I am looking for a solution in bash.

For example, if I have the string `MAIN`, then this script should return `test1` because the given string matches the pattern in the key of the first object.

I tried using `jq` but it seems to be doing the opposite of what I am trying to achieve. The `match` function accepts a regex and I am able to get all keys in the json that matches this regex. But in my case, the regex pattern is in the json and the string is the argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you do it in JQ:

```
first(.[keys_unsorted[] | select(. as $re | "MAIN" | test($re))].k)
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/5GsxrmZfTQW)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this. I was able to get my use case working using the information you provided.

Answer (score 1):

`$arg` is the string which you pass to the script, and `rules.json` is where your rule is stored.

The script extracts all keys from the JSON file and test them against the argument. Once the expected key is found, the script call `jq` again to get the value.

```bash
for pat in $(cat rules.json |jq 'keys_unsorted[]'); do 
  [[ $arg =~ $(echo $pat | jq -r '.') ]] && cat rules.json | jq -r ".[$pat].k" && break; 
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your solution works as well. But I was more inclined to mark someone else's reply as the answer because that solution is a more concise way to getting what I wanted to do.